# getting error JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout)

Tags: java, transactions

I'm getting the following error while executing a test for 300 users for an application.
 ***JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Prepare: NO vote***
can anyone please let me know what might be the solution to this..??
if i increase the transaction timeout will it help.

waiting for reply
Regards
Venky

Comment: which application server do you use?

Comment: Jetty Server with oracle DB

Comment: hi guys, anyone knows please help me on this....!!!